# Setting variable to capture group in while loop without altering $1

Tags: regex, perl, variable-assignment

Let's say you are going through a string that contains multiple occurrences of a similar string. E.g. we're looking for `ab` in a string `brabenanabeiabsenab`. I can then use a while loop to go over all these matches, and use $1 to go get  the match.

```
while ('brabenanabeiabsenab' =~ /ab/g) {
    my ($a) = $1 =~ /a/; # a
    my ($b) = $1 =~ /b/; # {empty}
}
```

So, when doing such operation `$1` is reduced to the match itself, and obviously `b` won't match any longer. What is the right way to make this work? Note that this is a simplification: in practice I really do need regular expressions and a while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while ('brabenanabeiabsenab' =~ /(ab)/g) {
    my $match = $1;
    my ($a) = $match =~ /(a)/;
    my ($b) = $match =~ /(b)/;
    ...
}
```

In this case, you can also do

```
while ('brabenanabeiabsenab' =~ /(a)(b)/g) {
    my $a = $1;
    my $b = $2;
    ...
}
```

Of course, if memory is no issue,

```
for ('brabenanabeiabsenab' =~ /ab/g) {
    my ($a) = /(a)/;
    my ($b) = /(b)/;
    ...
}
```